# File dialog won't open when called in promise return

Tags: reactjs, promise, upload, click, ref

I have a file upload dialog a user can access from a button:

```
<input
  ref={this.inputFileRef}
  type="file"
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
  onChange={e => this.onChange(e, this.props)}
/>
```

I have a function that processes a form submit, and does an async call:

```
handleSubmit = formData => {
  restClient(CREATE, 'projects', { formData })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      // other stuff
    });
}
```

I can click on the button inside the handleSubmit function like this (it gives me the file select dialog):

```
handleSubmit = formData => {
  this.props.inputFileRef.current.click();
  restClient(CREATE, 'projects', { formData })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      // other stuff
    });
}
```

But I CAN'T get it working inside the 'then' function:

```
handleSubmit = formData => {
  restClient(CREATE, 'projects', { formData })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.props.inputFileRef.current.click();
      // other stuff
    });
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you run the code that doesn't work? Does anything get logged to the console?

Comment: Good question Joseph.  I would expect an error in the console regarding `this` but it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  This is a problem with losing the user initiated action.

Comment: It's not a this issue. I'm pretty sure it's the async process.

Answer (score 1):

Since a promise is async, you lose the user initiated action from the initial click for the submit action and thus are no longer able to click the element within the then.  You will have to find another way.

Comment: Yeah. I think you're right. I guess I can dynamically add the file input object, then click on it from wherever it's initiated.

Comment: Can you switch the order so that the user clicks on the `<input type="file" />` first?  You can style it however you want if you make it visible by removing `display:none`

Comment: Nope - can't click on the actual item. I've got a table of items. Each row has a button. I only want one input element, but many buttons.

Comment: It's better to click on the actual input, but... if you need to use only one input button that way, perhaps maximize it's size behind the transparent table.  The onClick of the "other" buttons in each row could pass along the click to the input behind the table with extra information.

Comment: Why not many input elements?  How many are we talking about?  Have you tried many input elements?

Comment: I don't want extra file inputs. I'm just adding one dynamically as needed. That works well. I want something scalable, and I've seen problems with duplicating inputs for each row.

Comment: What works well?  Why isn't it scalable?  What problems have you seen with duplicating inputs for each row?